# Get Portal url (Host url) in ArcGIS Online Rest API

Tags: rest, arcgis, esri, arcgis-server, esri-arc-engine

I am new to Rest API and trying to develop a client for ArcGIS Online. I tried to login to ArcGIS.com using my login credentials and then see the maps that I have posted on the server. When I click on any map, it opens up in browser with a url like this.

**https://services.arcgis.com/N2SwjtBNabcd069C/arcgis/rest/services/IMap/FeatureServer/1**

Then I created a different login account, and then published map and tried to open that in browser it showed up with a different url like this

**https://services2.arcgis.com/N2SwjtBNabcd069C/arcgis/rest/services/IMap/FeatureServer/1**

Note the start of the url 
first one is

**https://services.arcgis.com/**

and second is

**https://services2.arcgis.com/**

Now my problem is when I try to login in my client application that I am developing. I am able to generate the token, account id and account name. **But how do I know which server should I search for to locate my layers(i.e. services2.arcgis.com or services.arcgis.com)? Where can I get this information from**

P.S: N2SwjtBNabcd069C in above url is the account id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you login, and generates your token you can make the following query to see the url of your content.

http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/content/users/<username>?f=json&token=<generatedToken >

This will return you the json that contains the url of your service.